# Heroku Database Detached

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails, postgres

I am new to Heroku and have deployed an application recently. It worked for a week before breaking. The issue lies on something related to Heroku. I see the following activity in Heroku.

```
api-maintenance@heroku.com: Detach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-contoured-49024)
```

Now when I access the application online I see:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

When I check the logs I see:

> F, [2022-12-19T11:51:30.936244 #4] FATAL -- : [bd4b4e41-9fc7-4d3d-b47b-f935f763a398] 2022-12-19T11:51:30.936316+00:00 app[web.1]: [bd4b4e41-9fc7-4d3d-b47b-f935f763a398] ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory

It seems Heroku ran some sort of routine that screwed up the database. Can someone please advise on what I should do to get the app up and running again? I am not being able to get any assistance from them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue with Heroku.

1- Heroku is deleting the free plans.

2- You need to move to what they call an "Eco Dyno". An eco dyno is basically a linux environment where your application will be run (think of it as similar to your local CLI).

3- What they don't tell you is that you need to request and pay for a postgres database to be attached to your app as an "Add on". They have a Mini plan which costs $5 per month (see attached). To find out more about this Mini plan, check this out: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#set-up-postgres-on-mac

4- When you subscribe to the postgres database you will need to go to terminal and do `heroku run rails db:migrate db:seed`.

That should solve the problem.